# jQuery Multiple file Upload, Retaining the files that have not been uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, file-upload

Need to upload the multiple files one by one. Say I've selected several files at a single stretch and display them in dynamically generating table. I'll upload one by one, as done here  http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Once I click start of a particular file, it gets uploaded and returned back(RequestDispatcher.include) to the same page but with no previously selected files.
But I need to retain the files which were not uploaded in previous request.

I went through the answers in web, but not satisfied with the answers.

Some possible ways that I thought which might help were:

1) Setting cookies

2) Storing all files temporarily before sending request and retrieving those files back to jsp page.

But I'm a newbie and I'm getting confused with all the answers.
Please help me on this.

```js
//onclick funtion triggered after clicking start button

function funIndividual(obj,e){

 var $this = $(obj);
    var rowIndex = $this.closest("tr").index();
 var singleFile =$("input[name=hidfileName]").eq(rowIndex).val();
  $('#strMode').val('UploadInd');
  $('#singleFile').val(singleFile);
   $('#fileupload').attr('action','servleturl');
   $('#fileupload').submit();
  }

}
```

```html
//Snippet to generate the dynamic table
$('#document').ready(function(){
 $('#multipleFiles').on('click',function(){
  if(document.getElementById('multipleFiles').value!=""){
      $( "#table tr" ).each( function(){
      this.parentNode.removeChild( this ); 
   });
   document.getElementById('multipleFiles').value="";
  }
 });
 
 $('#multipleFiles').on('change',function(){
     var inp = document.getElementById('multipleFiles');          
     var table = document.getElementById("table");
   for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i){ 
    var fileSize = "";
   var name = inp.files.item(i).name;    
   
   fileSize = bytesToSize(inp.files.item(i).size);
   var row = table.insertRow(0);
   row.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
   row.style.borderBottom ="solid thin gainsboro";
   row.id='trid';
   
   
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.style.width = '10px';
   cell1.style.textAlign ="";
   
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   cell2.style.width = '400px';
   cell2.style.textAlign ="left";
   
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   cell3.style.width = '300px';
   cell3.style.textAlign ="center";
   
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
   cell4.style.width = '390px';
   cell4.style.textAlign = "center";
   cell1.innerHTML = "<td><span class='preview'></span></td>";
   cell2.innerHTML = "<td align='left'><input type='hidden' id='hidfileName' name='hidfileName' value="+name+"><p class='name'>"+name+"</p><strong class='error text-danger'>"+fileFormatSupported+"</strong></td>";
   cell3.innerHTML = "<td align='center'><p class='size'>"+fileSize+"</p><div style='display:none' id ='progressbar'"+i+" class='progress progress-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' aria-valuenow='0'><div class='progress-bar style='display:none' progress-bar-success' style='width:10%;'></div></div></td>";
   cell4.innerHTML = "<td align='center'><span id='btnStartInd"+i+"' name='btnStartInd' class='btn btn-primary start' onclick='javascript:funIndividual(this,event)' "+isValidFile+"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload'></i><span> Start</span></span>&nbsp;<span onclick='javascript:funcancelInd(this,event)' id='btnCancelInd"+i+"' class='btn btn-warning'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle'></i><span> Cancel</span></span></td>"+ "</tr>";
   
   }

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try look at this

[link for multiple upload](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html)

Try read the tutorial and download the file, very simple and easy to change in :-)

Comment: Answer is useful, but I can't use PHP and Ajax requests. If you can see the code snippet I've added, you may get clear idea about the code.